# How do I use testdisk?

Tags: partitioning, testdisk

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a walkthrough in testdisk. I wouldn't ask for this, but I caused this problem by trying to fix things myself using testdisk without really knowing how, so now I'm nervous to try anything else.


I was messing with it trying to fix another problem and now I only have 1 partition out of the 9 that there was. When I use Analyze, everything comes up exactly like it used to and all my files are still there.

```
D FAT16 >32.
D HPFS - NTFS
D HPFS - NTFS
D Linux
D Linux
D Linux
D Linux
D Linux
D Linux Swap
```

Now what do I do to rewrite the old partition structure to the disk? Also if it helps, the FAT16 is the Dell Utility and I'm pretty sure the 1st Linux partition just 'holds' the rest of the Linux partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No

Testdisk shows a `D` mark on all your partitions which indicates that these can not be recovered by the current version of Testdisk.

Comment: I can change them to P, *, or L but I dont know which ones to change to what.

Comment: P -Primary partition
S - Secondary partition
D -Delete partion

use appropriate choice for each partition

Comment: L -logical partition

Comment: I know what they stand for, but I dont know what to set each partition as. I dont know which each one would be

Comment: Try to make it  P ,if not possible make it L

Comment: @bobtahog : means it is not recoverable by testdisk :-(

Comment: I rewrote the partition structure but now when I try booting from harddrive I get `error: unknown filesystem`. Everything was recovered OK, but now I can't boot :(

Comment: Try to boot from livecd and update grub